# setuptools "Upload failed (400): Form data is not correctly encoded in UTF-8", why?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, setuptools

I'm trying to upload my documentation to PyPI, but I'm getting an error message *Upload failed (400): Form data is not correctly encoded in UTF-8*.  When testing the individual files with *iconv*, they do seem to be correctly encoded in utf-8.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$ python3.3 setup.py upload_docs                                     
running upload_docs
running build_sphinx
Running Sphinx v1.2
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
Submitting documentation to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (400): Form data is not correctly encoded in UTF-8
```

Uploading manually works fine.

Comment: What does `$file yourfilename` show?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Do you mean `file doc/build/singlehtml/index.html: HTML document text`?  I'm not sure if I understand exactly what information you need.

Comment: does it work if you [upload the zipped docs to pypi manually](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPiDocumentationHosting)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, it does.  Edited the question now to clearly state this.

Comment: does `upload_docs` command work now? Does it work if you update `setuptools`? Are you sure your settings are correct e.g., you are not passing a list instead of a string somewhere? Try to rebuild the docs from clean state. Otherwise [report the issue](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues?status=new&status=open).